# Codename One - Reduce the loading time of a web-app

Tags: codenameone

I have a Codename One web-app that, after showing the logo, it remains completely blank and white for a variable time (from few seconds to more that ten seconds). My Internet connection is very fast (optical fiber).

Is there any tip to reduce the loading time of a Codename One web-app? The build size is 663kb and the generated application is 10,5MB (unzipped).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome has some really nice benchmarking tools that help point out the time spent on each stage. You should run these and make sure that the downloaded binaries are gzipped so the download isn't the bottleneck.

Also make sure to run your tests against a deployed app and not on the preview which might exhibit different behavior.

In terms of the app, try to show a form quickly without any server requests or IO. Once you do that defer the code to the actual loading block later. If you trigger a server call this will significantly slow down loading.